# Why is reading files on AWS S3 Glacier very slow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I have just started learning about AWS and come to know AWS S3 has several choices (example: S3 standard, S3 glacier). In general, I believe storages where we can get files faster are more expensive, and those where we can get files slower are cheaper.

I would like to know how this works in terms of technology. Why is the cost lower (probably for Amazon) if the reading speed is lower, and vice versa?

Comment: Glacier is using some storage medium offering low cost and infrequent access.  We don't know exactly what it is using, but AWS aims for Glacier to compete with on premise storage to magnetic tape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glacier is an archival data store. It is meant to store data which is **very rarely accessed**, primary for backup purposes. Exact details of how AWS stores its data are unknown, but its speculated it is stored and shelved on custom tape storage, or something similar, which is much cheaper then any regular hard drives used for frequent data access. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Glacier) writes:

> The Register claimed that Glacier runs on Spectra T-Finity **tape libraries** with LTO-6 tapes.[10][11] Others have conjectured Amazon using off-line **shingled magnetic recording** hard drives, multi-layer **Blu-ray optical discs**, or an alternative proprietary storage technology.

Comment: If you read the entire Wikipedia page, you'll see that there isn't a consensus on what Glacier actually is using.  Therefore, the answer you gave here doesn't really answer the question, and also could become stale later on.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I explicitly wrote "its speculated". There is no more details, unless some employ from AWS will release the inside info on how glacier works.